# How I calc range of date's from 2 numbers to 2 strings

Tags: c#

> I want all people that there age is 27
>
> how i calc the start and the end date?

```
    ss.startAge = (DateTime.Now.Year - startAge).ToString() +
 "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");

    ss.endAge = (DateTime.Now.Year - (endAge-1)).ToString() + 
"-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

> i know that i need to sub 1 day but if the end age is need to be
>   1999-12-31 because the calc is above is give 2000-01-01 how i need to
>   write the code that the end age will be correct

how i calc the end date correctly?

Comment: Please format it a little more. Its not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please add a short example: What is your input data? what do you want to calculate? What is the expected result?